# Java - Infinite Recursion

Tags: java, recursion

When attempting to run this line of code, the initialisation of `temperatureInKelvin` is highlighted with the message "Infinite Recursion" and I can't think of any way to fix this.

```
double temperatureInKelvin(double temperatureInFahrenheight) {
    double fahrenheightToKelvinCalculation = (temperatureInFahrenheight - 32.0 * 5.0 / 9.0 + 273.15);
    return temperatureInKelvin(fahrenheightToKelvinCalculation);
}
```

Comment: What do you think that calling `temperatureInKelvin` inside of the method `temperatureInKelvin` without any condition to stop it will produce?

Comment: Perhaps `return fahrenheightToKelvinCalculation;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to re-call `temperatureInKelvin` at all. Just return the value you calculated in `fahrenheightToKelvinCalculation`. Note, BTW, that your parenthesis are wrong, and you should subtract 32 from the Fahrenheit value before multiplying it by 5/9:

```
double temperatureInKelvin(double temperatureInFahrenheight){
    return (temperatureInFahrenheight - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0 + 273.15;
}
```

Comment: or you will need to provide a condition which will guide recursion until that condition is not true (Kind of stating the obvious)